# Difference of pointer pointing to integer variable always gives 1 as answer?

Tags: c, pointers

I cant understand the output of following program. `p` is pointing to `a`, and `q` is pointing to `b`, `r` is pointing to `c`. But the difference of two pointers is always 1

```
main()
{
    int a,c,b;
    int *p,*q,*r;
    p = &a;
    q = &b;
    r = &c;
    b = p - r;
    printf("(%d) - (%d) = %d",p,q,b);
}
```

The output of above program is

```
(1331616036) - (1331616028) = 1
```

Comment: This code invokes *undefined behaviour*.  It's not valid to perform arithmetic on pointers to unrelated objects.

Comment: Why are you displaying the values of `p`, `q`, and then `p-r` instead of `p-q`?